# Django server is not working on Virtual Server

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I have a server that is using Ubuntu. I have uploaded my Django project to the server. And ran the command:
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`

But when I try to go the website in browser I get `The requested URL could not be retrieved` error.

What can be the reason of that?

Comment: what is the result if you run : python manage.py runserver  without the ip and port ?

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis The problem was that my internet provider blocked the IP address of  the housting provider so I just used VPN and everything worked pretty well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python manage.py runserver {YOUR_PUBLIC_IP}:80
```

Also you need to check firewall settings, make sure that 80 port is opened

Comment: Yeah! Thanks but the problem was that my internet provider blocked the IP address of  the housting provider so I just used VPN and everything worked pretty well :)